# Wired connection problem

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, internet, connection

I've recently been updating from Lynx and am currently at 11.10
However when I restarted the computer I couldn't get any wired connection (which is what I use). When I click at the top it just says that the connection is disconnected, which it isn't ... I'm a bit of a newbie at Ubuntu so I may have missed something obvious but if any of you guys could help that would be great! :D

Edit: My ifconfig result is

```
Link evaluate: local loopback
Inet addr:127.0.0.1 Scope:Host
Up Loopback Running MTU :16436 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
Collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes (0.0 B)
```

I've checked the cable and that is definately working. I also get `Usage: dmesg [-c] [-n level] [-r] [-s bufsize]`

Comment: Could you include the output of **ifconfig** ?

Comment: The most obvious thing to do is check the cable. If it's right it's likely a driver issue. Can you add more info about your hardware?. Can you add the output o *dmesg | grep eth*?

Comment: @Kieran Your edits are coming through as a logged out user, that's why you can't edit your question right away.

Comment: The | is not an l, but a pipe. This is likely why the command is failing.

Answer (score 0):

> Easy route:

Use `sudo dhclient` and hope your DHCP server assigns an IP address, default gateway, and name servers (DNS).

> Long route:

`ifconfig` on it's own only display configured network cards. It seems for now your network card is unconfigured and you are viewing your loopback adapter which is a default adaptor that should always be there.

Try `ifconfig -a`. This will display all cards available and the ethernet interface id for those cards. Look for something like `eth0` or `eth1`.

To quickly configure a card, do something like this:
`sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2`.

Of course `eth0` is dependant on the result of your `ifconfig -a` and the IP address is dependant on your environment.

This will bring your machine online. Now you can hopefully ping your default gateway.

To assign your default gateway do this:
`sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1`

Again the IP `192.168.0.1` is dependant on your environment. If you have a Windows machine you can do `ipconfig -all` to get most of the required information.

Now you can hopefully ping the Internet, but you won't be able to resolve names. So you can `ping 196.25.1.1` but not `ping www.google.com`. For that you have to assign a DNS server. To do this:

Edit /etc/resolv.conf

I use `mc -e` (Midnight Commander) but you might prefer to use `vi` which is built into most Unix systems.

Add the following to `resolv.conf`:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`

and save. Now you should be able to ping the Internet and get online using a browser. You are temporarily using Google's public name server at `8.8.8.8`.

At this point we normally install Webmin :-) http://www.webmin.com/

Webmin makes is 10x easier to configure and check network cards. In Webmin, use the `Networking` / `Network Configuration` and then:

`Network Interfaces` (IP address)
`Routing and Gateways` (Default gateway)
`Hostname and DNS Client` (DNS servers)

menus to configure your card.

> Checking `/etc/network/interfaces`

You might also want to check `/etc/network/interfaces` because that is where the resultant configuration information is stored. On a DHCP enabled machine you have something like this:

```
user@computer:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

On a fixed IP machine you will have values like this (depends on environment):

```
user@computer2:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The auto command
auto lo eth1

# The loopback network interface
iface lo inet loopback

# The rest
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Please note the above file contains just the IP address and default gateway.

The sum of our solution is to get the IP address, default gateway, and DNS servers (in `/etc/resolv.conf`) right. Good luck, this can sometimes be a bit of a nightmare if it doesn't work right out the box / upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

he way I fixed mine (same prob)was to go to 'Edit Connection's change the "Connection name"

to Auto(eth0)-MTU:is Automaic(DHCP)-Tick both "Require IP4 addressing for this connection to complete,and "Available to all users"

IP v6 Settings: Should be "Ignore", and also tick "Available to all users"